# Unable to add items to cart - UnAuthorized access

Tags: spartacus-storefront

[image: Unable to add items to cart]

Trying to setup local spartacus with `2011 Commerce Cloud` and `spartacussampledata`. Few restful endpoints are throwing 401 unauthorized access. Followed this link for setup: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries

Comment: Did you check backgroud console log?

Comment: `INFO  [hybrisHTTP5] [RestHandlerExceptionResolver] Translating exception [org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException]: It's not allowed to execute this call from the current channel`

Comment: @mkysoft here you go the backend error

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found any soulution?

Comment: Heey @Irus! Could you solve this? I'm having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to contribute!

Here in my project I am instantiating a Spartacua TUA (Telco Utilities Accelerator)

I've been having this problem "It's not allowed to execute this call from the current channel" and in my case the solution was to review the property "api.compatibility.b2c.channels" which was with the B2B value for the B2C store. I changed the value and it worked correctly again!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it by updating the correct channel under Basesite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYEAN.png)

Answer (score 0):

To shed some light on the issue.

If you are receiving a response from the backend that says `It's not allowed to execute this call from the current channel`, then you have misconfigured your storefront.

Basically, the endpoint is most likely hitting an endpoint used for B2B or B2C depending on which 'channel' you are currently in.

For example, in the screenshot, you are currently in B2C, but you are most likely calling the B2B channel. You should be calling the endpoint with `users/${userId}/carts/${cartId}/entries?quantity=${quantity}`, but instead, you are calling an endpoint with `orgUsers/${userId}/carts/${cartId}/entries?quantity=${quantity}`.

Notice users vs orgUsers as the difference.